# get latest record from table using postgresql

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, postgresql-9.6

I have table employee as below,

```
id|name1|number
--|-----|------
01|test |100
02|test1|101
03|test2|102
```

I am using jpa with eclipselink implementation and database is postgresql.
Here my requirement is I want to get latest record using select query. Can anyone suggest the query to get latest record always.
Thanks,

Comment: By latest you mean the largest id? Try `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: No, latest (recent) record.

Comment: How do you specify "latest"?

Comment: @mounish Please check my answer. :)

Comment: Until you tell people HOW you DEFINE the "latest" record and HOW a query can identify it from that definition then the question is utterly undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add updatedDate field in the entity class.

> So I'll like to know if is there a SIMPLE way around my problem, meaning having @PrePersist or @PreUpdate or even other workaround to set the lastModified field still using session

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "name")  
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "number")  
    private Long number;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")  
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)  
    private Date updatedAt;  

    // getter setter

    @PreUpdate  
    public void setChangeDate() {  
       this.updatedAt = new Date();  
    }  

}
```

You can use JPA query. This exam:

```
String query = "SELECT emp FROM Employee emp order by updatedAt desc limit 1 ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below query for getting the appropriate result from mysql

```
select * from employee order by id desc limit 1
```